# como o lua (corona sdk) roda no android

Tags: android, lua

Estou testando o corona sdk para android, e estou achando muito bom.

Claro que são testes simples, mas rodou muito bem em um celular antigo com android 2.3, e o mesmo apk rodou no android 6.

Tando a carga do programa como sua execução, foram bem.

Os apk gerados pelo corona sdk, são bytecodes do JVM do android, ou é compilado em c++ para android (ndk?)?

Como a linguagem é lua, fiquei curioso em saber se o interpretador lua foi portado para java ou é um port em c++ para android?

Fiz um programa parecido  com o sdk do android em java, e não parece rodar mais rápido.

Comment: Ele gera código nativo para iOS ou Android.